# Laptop doesn't connect to WiFi if it has less than 5 bars

Tags: windows, drivers, internet-connection, wifi-driver

So I've had this issue with my laptop's network card (Ralink RT3290) where everyone around me can get on the WiFi that's not that far away while I can't because I have less than 5 bars of reception.

This issue is so weird because I've had it through Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 and with numerous versions of drivers and numerous access points. What's even weirder is that a friend of mine who has the Intel i3 version of my Intel i5 HP ProBook 4540s can connect with relatively more ease than me. It is really irritating that I always need to plug my phone and connect to the access point then enable USB tethering to be able to connect to any WiFi (thankfully my room is really close to the router)

Comment: Try the latest driver from HP again.  http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5229456&lang=en&cc=us

Comment: It is possible the wireless card is defective.

Comment: Try the driver from Ralink....http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that either your card is defective, or, more likely, the aerial on the card has come loose / off.   I also suspect that the cards receiving sensitivity is way higher then the access points - so it can receive data OK, but can't transmit back.

It could be that the card is defective (defective cap, inductor or quartz), and that it a strong signal is compensating for slight timing issues of the card, much like you can pick up analog radio stations even if your radio is not tuned in exactly.